# SQL pivot or nested gridview?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, gridview, pivot

I have my data stored in a single table and they want the data displayed in a specific way. The data currently reads out of a gridview with the following headings

```
Batch   Unit        Amount 
105      6767687    82.76
105      9653435    98.72
106      4567897    7.41
107      4567321    5.21
108      3216541    6.00
```

and they want it instead to look like this.

```
Batch    Unit    Amount
105              (Total Amount)     
         6767687  82.76
         9653435  98.72
106              (Total AMount
         4567321  5.21
```

and so on.

I've tried nested with no luck and I'm not sure if a pivot will be the best for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the nested grids will be your best options.  SQL `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` are more for transforming fields to records and records to fields.  You could possibly get away with an SQL `GROUP BY` statement, but you would lose detail in the data, and would have to perform functions (SUM, AVG, COUNT, etc.) on the rest of the data in order to use it.
[This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/e06010/grouping-in-asp-net-gridview/) may be of some assistance.

EDIT:  I was able to duplicate exactly what you are asking utilizing [THIS](http://technico.qnownow.com/grouping-gridview-aspnet/) example of nested gridviews. Just substitute in your data connection and field names.